# How to separate release and debug builds in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt4, qmake

I would like to put binaries of release and debug build in different folders beside source code. in .pro file:

```
CONFIG(debug){
    DESTDIR = ./debug
    OBJECTS_DIR = debug/.obj
    MOC_DIR = debug/.moc
    RCC_DIR = debug/.rcc
    UI_DIR = debug/.ui
}

CONFIG(release){
    DESTDIR = ./release
    OBJECTS_DIR = release/.obj
    MOC_DIR = release/.moc
    RCC_DIR = release/.rcc
    UI_DIR = release/.ui
}
```

For release builds everything is good. I have a ./release directory in root of project. But for debug build, qmake didn't create a debug directory, it's name is `release` (again!):

```
qmake CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=local 
// generates release and put everything in that directory
// but I want debug directory !
```

**Update:**

Replacing order of debug and release, makes debug directory. Only last config is seen by qmake...

Comment: Doesn't this happen automatically? For me it does - I get different builds in separate directory in the same path as the project folder.

Comment: @ddriver You're probably on Windows...

Comment: Yep, I guess it is different in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really have to do in-source builds and have separate output directories, I think you need to change your conditionals per [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#config-config) to

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = ./debug
    OBJECTS_DIR = debug/.obj
    MOC_DIR = debug/.moc
    RCC_DIR = debug/.rcc
    UI_DIR = debug/.ui
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = ./release
    OBJECTS_DIR = release/.obj
    MOC_DIR = release/.moc
    RCC_DIR = release/.rcc
    UI_DIR = release/.ui
}
```

Don't ask me why, though. IMHO QMake is an abomination that should be avoided at all cost...

Comment: Adding mysterious `debug|release` fixed everything. I don't ask why!

Comment: Care to elaborate on your sentiments towards qmake? qmake is a lot better than many other build management tools I've used before...

Comment: @stephelton The language is obscure and very inconsistent, the code base is a mess and largely unmaintainable. Even the [Qt devs agree](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/10/12/to-make-or-not-to-make-qmake-and-beyond). It doesn't include a *configure-stage* where the user can tweak things or the author can search for headers, libraries and tools and it is very much tied to Qt, pretty much useless for non-Qt projects. qmake is now being replaced with [qbs](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/02/15/introducing-qbs).

Comment: @MichaelWild thanks for the info. The "configure-stage" you mention has frustrated me quite a bit. However, as I mentioned, it's still a lot better than many alternatives, and I've used it effectively for non-Qt projects. Do you have any recommendations? It's virtues, by my reckoning, are that it's cross platform (in theory anyway -- I've only really used it with Linux...), it supports large, complex codebases without much effort, and it works well both from command line and IDE. And it's painless to install with any modern package manager.

Comment: I use [CMake](http://cmake.org), it's very powerful and quite feature-complete. However, it's language also has its deficiencies and it is not to everybody's taste... You might want to give [gyp](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/), [scons](http://scons.org), [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) or [premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) a try.

Answer (score 3):

The real solution is to do out-of-source builds. That way you don't have to reconfigure every time you switch from debug to release build and back. Do do this, use the following:

```
mkdir build-dbg
cd build-dbg
qmake ../foo.pro CONFIG+=debug
cd ..
mkdir build-rel
cd build-rel
qmake ../foo.pro CONFIG+=release
```

As an added plus you don't pollute the source tree with build debris.

Comment: For some specific reasons, I have only one folder for each project on server and build script on server tries only level 1 directories... I do not like to mix binaries in source directory of course.